# Pressing-Down-Lemma for Jech's notion of stationary sets

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

So, apparently there is a variant of the Pressing-Down-Lemma (or Fodor's Lemma) for Jech's notion of stationarity, i.e. for sets in $[X]^\lambda$. Does anybody know a citable source for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the references in his Handbook article, the following should include the theorem you're looking for.

Namely, if $S$ is a stationary subset of $[X]^\lambda$ and $f(x)\in x$ for all $x\in S\setminus\{\varnothing\}$, then there is a stationary $S'$ on which $f$ is constant.

> *Thomas J. Jech*, [**Some combinatorial problems concerning uncountable cardinals**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=325397), *Ann. Math. Logic* **5** (1972-73), 165--198.

The theorem is Theorem 3.2 on p.179 (this is actually part (d) of the theorem, which is a spillover to page 180).

Comment: Thank you! That LOOKED like what I needed, but unfortunately it turned out (after toying with it for a while) it wasn't.
My situation is this: I have a map $f:[\kappa]^\omega\to[\kappa]^{<\omega}$ and I'm supposed to use the pressing-down-lemma to get a stationary subset on which $f$ is constant. It seems like the above version doesn't quite get me there :-(

Comment: You wanted a reference for the pressing down lemma for $[X]^\lambda$, right? That's the reference. Maybe you're not looking for the generalization of the pressing down lemma after all.

Comment: sorry, I was still editing when I accidentally hit enter :D

Comment: Well, my comment still stands. This function looks familiar. Is it from the context of proper forcing, or from stationary tower forcing?

Comment: The precise situation is from Todorcevic's "A dichotomy for P-ideals of countable sets" in the proof, that his forcing order is proper (Fundamenta Mathematicae vol.166 (2000), Lemma 2, page 261)

Comment: I don't see it in the paper. Also in what sense is the map "pressing down"?

Comment: I quote: "It follows that $Y_0 = [\mathcal I]^\omega$. By the Pressing Down Lemma, applied in $M$, there is a finite set $F_0$ in $M$ and a stationary subset $S$ of $[\mathcal I]^\omega$ in $M$ such that $F_0$ witnesses $a\in Y_0$ for all $a\in S$."

The context is that $\mathcal I$ is a P-Ideal, and $Y_0$ is defined as the sets in $[\mathcal I]^\omega$ such that there is a certain finite set witnessing a certain property...
in my .pdf, the section is almost at the bottom of the page labeled 261.

Comment: Hmm, this is too much for me to process and I'm dreadfully tired. My suggestion is that you ask this in a focused way over a new question (give reference to the paper, and ask what this particular thing means). I'll see that tomorrow when I wake up.

Comment: Will do. Still, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It's my pleasure!